# Increment/Decrement Confusion

Tags: java, increment, decrement

What is happening when we decrement the code here:

`temp[--countArray[getDigit(position, input[tempIndex], radix)]]`

If temp is 1 in this case:  are we decrementing first so that we are assigning to 0?  How immediate is this decrement?  It always seems to confuse me within array brackets.

Comment: It decrements `countArray[getDigit(position, input[tempIndex], radix)]` and uses the decremented value as the index for `temp`.

Comment: "If countArray is 1 in this case"—`countArray` cannot be 1. It has to be an array.

Comment: @khelwood My mistake, meant to write 'if temp index is 1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try unpacking the brackets on different levels of indentation:

```
temp[                                                // get this index in temp
    --                                               // decrement by 1
    countArray[                                      // get this index in countArray
        getDigit(position, input[tempIndex], radix)  // call getDigit()
    ]
]
```

In human-readable terms, it calls `getDigit()` to index into `countArray`, then decrements that value and uses it to index into `temp`.

---

The decrement operator `--x` is different from `x--` because of what it returns. By the end of the operation, `x` always ends up as one less than it was, but `--x` returns the *new* value of `x`, while `x--` returns the *old* value of `x` from before it was decremented. The same applies for `++x` and `x++`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me break this down some. Here's some code that's equivalent to above:

```
int digit = getDigit(position, input[tempIndex], radix);
countArray[digit]--;
int count = countArray[digit];
temp[count] // Do something with the value
```

Incidentally, this is a classic illustration of why you shouldn't sacrifice clarity to brevity.